# Type Mismatch VBA array

Tags: arrays, ms-access, vba

I keep getting a type mismatch error when I try to run my code. I'm trying to store number in an array and then calculate their sum.

```
Sub Exercise()

    Dim Sum As Integer

    Dim A(1 to 5) As Integer
    A(1) = 35
    A(2) = 71
    A(3) = 42
    A(4) = 53
    A(5) = 109

    Sum = 0
    Sum = (Sum + A)

    For A = 1 To 5
    Next Sum

    MsgBox Sum

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you meant to do this:

```
Sub Exercise()
    Dim Sum As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim A(1 To 5) As Integer

    A(1) = 35
    A(2) = 71
    A(3) = 42
    A(4) = 53
    A(5) = 109

    Sum = 0
    For i = 1 To 5
        Sum = (Sum + A(i))
    Next i

    MsgBox Sum
End Sub
```

Notice the differences. You set `Sum = 0` prior to the loop, then use an iteration variable `i` to loop through the values of `A` by calling them using `A(i)`. This adds each `A(i)` to the running total defined by `Sum`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `A` as your loop counter, it's your array.

You probably intend to do this:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 5
    Sum = Sum + A(i)
Next
```

---

Note that `Sum` is already initialized to `0`, so this line is superfluous:

```
Sum = 0
```

And the line that tries to assign `Sum = (Sum + A)` can just be removed, you can't add an `Integer` with an array.